# Mysql Multiple Concat Inner Join, only give one Name

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I have three Tables.

```
table1 = anlass 
table2 = stammdaten_beziehungen
table3 = parameter_zuweisungen_anl
```

It gaves me this ERROR: Subquery returns more than 1 row

But what i need, is all 'BeziehKuBez' Comma separated in one column.
eg. Beziehname1, Beziehname2, ...

If have test it with, `CONCAT_WS(',', BeziehKuBez)`. But give me the same one. Could I do this with a while loop? But I dont know how?!

**Update:**
Regarding [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509945/mysql-multiple-concat-inner-join-only-give-one-name/1509975#1509975):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` gives he same output as `concat()`.

Only one name per "Anlass". But i need, Multiple names comma separated for one "Anlass".

**TABLE STRUCTURE:**

*Table Anlass:*

AnlID, anlass_name

*Table Stammdaten_beziehungen*

BeziehID, Beziehkubez

*Table Parameter_zuweisung_anl*

ZuwAnlID, ZuwAnlAnlNr,ZuwAnlBeziehID

**INFO**
ZuwAnlAnlNr linked to Anlass.AnlID
ZuwAnlBeziehID linked to Beziehung.BeziehID

This is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`BeziehKuBez`) AS Bezname
FROM `stammdaten_beziehungen` AS Beziehung, `anlass` AS anlass
    INNER JOIN `parameter_zuweisungen_anl` 
        ON  Beziehung.BeziehID = parameter_zuweisungen_anl.ZuwAnlBeziehID
WHERE ZuwAnlAnlNr = Anlass.AnlID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).  You should also group by something:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(BeziehKuBez) AS Bezname
FROM stammdaten_beziehungen AS Beziehung,
anlass AS anlass
INNER JOIN parameter_zuweisungen_anl ON Beziehung.BeziehID = parameter_zuweisungen_anl.ZuwAnlBeziehID
WHERE ZuwAnlID = Anlass.AnlID
GROUP BY ?
```

Comment: Its the Same Output, only One Name in a row.

I have a table "parameter_zuweisung_anl" with ID's from "anlass" and "Beziehung".
"Beziehung" has a column with a Name. 
This Name must linked to the "Anlass".

Comment: did you GROUP BY Anlass.AnlID?

Comment: hi, thx for yor spended time ;)
it was not "WHERE ZuwAnlID = Anlass.AnlID" i've corrected them.
This is the right one "WHERE ZuwAnlAnlNr = Anlass.AnlID".

But yet, mysql gave me an Error like: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

mhmm, ALL or ANY Dont work ?!